# What is the remainder when dividing $((1997!+11)!+29)!$ by $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

This question appeared in one of the national exams in Saudi Arabia which was on Saturday, November $29, 1997$.

> If today is Saturday, what day of the week will it be
> $((1997!+11)!+29)!$ days from now?

Actually I do not know how to start. I saw a similar problem asking $10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now, it was a simple one.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Hint 1 : What is remainder when $11!$ is divided by $7$? Hint 2 : This one is simpler.

Comment: @cosmo5 $11! \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 7)}$. Then?

Comment: @SomeGuy Sir I have mentioned that I do not know how to start.

Comment: @cosmo5 there is no $11!$ in the problem, it is $(1997!+11)!$

Comment: Hint: The entire expression is ultimately just gonna be (some number larger than 7)!.

Comment: By the linked dupes, the product of any sequence of $\,n\ge 7\,$ consecutive integers is divisible by $7$ (in fact here $7$ actually occurs as one of the consecutive integers in the prodcut $n!)\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$((1997!+11)!+29)!$ is your expression. We know that $(1997!+11)!+29$ is a very big integer bigger than $7$, thus $((1997!+11)!+29)!$ is the product of all numbers equal to and less than it, which includes $7$, meaning that the number of days is divisible by $7$, thus the only thing that changes is the week, not the day. For example, if you add $7$ days to Sunday, you'd get Sunday. Thus, if we add a number of days divisible by $7$ to Saturday, we end on Saturday. Thus, adding $((1997!+11)!+29)!$ days, which is divisible by $7$ to Saturday will keep it a Saturday.

Comment: If suffices to notice that $(1997!+11)!+29 > 7$

Comment: You mean $7!$? I see what you mean

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque I answered it before it was closed, should I still delete it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

Which day it is the $n$-th day from today, $n$ satisfying the following?
$$n \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Notice for $n \ge 7$, $n! \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.